How do I sum corresponding values of distinct records
So I have to write a query for a table grouping by 5 columns and fetch the sum of one of the columns based on the grouping.
Now, in the database I have duplicate records. So I am getting incorrect sum.
So how do I fetch the sum of distinct records with respect to just column A.
Example:
Note: this is just an example. I have a lot more columns and data.I have just mentioned the columns which I want



A
B
C
D
E
F
G




400001
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
20
1460.00


400001
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
10
1460.00


400002
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
0
5556.00


400002
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
10
5556.00


400003
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
20
1200.00


400003
101
2024-05-06
OOS
MRP
20
1200.00



select B,C, D, E, F, 
sum(G) as Totals from Table 
where 
B= '101' and C = '2024-05-06'
group  by  B,C, D, E, F

This is giving 5 records. Though the number of records are correct but the summation result is incorrect as there are many duplicate records.
So I tried
select distinct A,B,C, D, E, F, 
sum(G) as Totals from Table 
where 
B= 'value' and date = '2024-05-06'
group  by  B,C, D, E, F,A

This is grouping by the column A and giving me 88 records and the summation is also incorrect.
I am expecting to get a result which consists data grouping by B,C, D, E, F and sum of G column for distinct A column
So I was trying to get those 5 records with correct summed data.
database using : postgreSQL

It seems the table in your question shows the input data? Please add another table that shows the expected result.

By the way, your query does not return five rows for your sample data, but three, see https://dbfiddle.uk/BHDXoQAT. Another reason why you should add the expected result.

@JonasMetzler yes but in real time I have a lot more data and lot many columns. So I have just mentioned the columns which are important to me and need to include distinct records w.r.t column A and group by B,C,D,E and F and sum of column G based on the grouping

Please add all clarifications and other information to your question, not as comments. And add a table to your question that shows the expected result rather than describing it only. Otherwise, it is very hard to understand and I guess you won't get good answers.

If there are duplicates, first filter them out by doing a distinct on all the columns then perform the sum which is desired on the result set.
The query should look something like:
select A, B, C, D, E, F, sum(G) as Totals
from ( select distinct A, B, C, D, E, F, G from Table ) as temp
group by A, B, C, D, E, F;

I made a small example on dbfiddle, you can check it out.

This query looks very strange and the result is just identic to simply this query: select distinct a,b,c,d,e,f,g from table;

@atish.s no this does not work.

@JonasMetzler how it is strange? the 'from' part is selecting from a virtual table of distinct records and doing the aggregation based on those distinct records.

@SubhashreeNayak can you share the query you have written? maybe an example on fiddledb with some sample data would be helpful as well.
